# Unrecognized IP address showing in WP site URL

Tags: wordpress, ip, ddos, pingback

I have an odd situation. Website of a client (just took it over from someone else) isn't loading properly. The index page text is loading, but none of the resources (css, js, images, etc) are loading. Looking at the console, getting 404 errors. Looking at the sources (Chrome developer tools), each of those files have "79.170.40.173" at the front of the referencing URL.

Example:

```
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='storefront-style-css'  href='http://79.170.40.173/thorasthreads.com/wp-content/themes/storefront/style.css?ver=2.1.7' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I looked at the IP addresses for the domain, et al, and none of them match this IP address. Best answer I can figure is a pingback DDOS since it's a WP site.

1) Am I correct?

2) How do I fix it? I've found preventative measures, but nothing on cleaning it up. I've tried blocking access to the xmlrpc.php file in .htaccess, but that doesn't fix it.

Comment: can you provide site link

Comment: @RajkumarGour  http://thorasthreads.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these constants in your wp-config.php file

```
define('WP_HOME','http://thorasthreads.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://thorasthreads.com');
```

after that go to `wp-admim->settings->general` settings

and change the url of both siteurl and home.